# How can I handle this error : Call to undefined method App\Models\client::findOrFails() and send form data with Js formData object?

Tags: javascript, laravel, request, form-data

I have a list of clients with their id. I access to the details of a client with his id in the DB. On the client details page it's possible to update his informations with a modal form.

I'm using JS formData to send the form's informations.

So when sending the informations updated in the form in post to the server I want to reload this client Details page and send the data updated. But I'm getting this error : **Call to undefined method App\Models\client::findOrFails()** and I'm just getting the crsf_token of the form.

Here is the routes:

```
Route::get('clients/client_numero/{id}', [ClientDetailsController::class, 'edit_client']);

Route::post('clients/client_numero/{id}', [ClientDetailsController::class, 'update_client']);
```

The controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClientDetailsController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function edit_client ($id){

        return view('admin.clientDetails', ['client' => client::findOrFail($id)]);
    }


    public function update_client ($id, Request $request) {

        
       

         return view ('admin.clientDetails', ['client' => client::findOrFails($id)]);
    }

}
```

The JS code :

```
 
// Getting the informations from the form to modify  client informations


let modifiyClientInformationsForm = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm');

//-----------------------Name----------------------------------
var nameInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_name').value ;

//------------------------Prenom------------------------

var prenomInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_prenom').value ;

//-----------------------Contact----------------------------


var contactInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_contact').value ;

//---------------------------Email------------------------------------

var emailInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_email').value ;

//---------------------------Pays------------------------------------


var paysInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_pays').value ;

//---------------------------Ville------------------------------------


var villeInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_ville').value ;

//----------------------Type----------------------------------------------

var typeInput = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_type').value ;

    //-----------------------crsf Token-------------------------------------


var formToken = document.getElementById('modifiyClientInformationsForm_token').value;

  


//------------------Creating formData object---and---submit form event--------------------------------



modifiyClientInformationsForm.addEventListener('submit' , function(e) {

 


var action= modifiyClientInformationsForm.getAttribute("action");

        e.preventDefault();

var data = new FormData();

    data.append( "_token", Laravel.csrfToken );

    data.append('_name', nameInput ) ;
   data.append('prenom', prenomInput );
   data.append('contact', contactInput );
    data.append('email', emailInput );
    data.append('ville', villeInput );
    data.append('pays', paysInput );
    data.append('type', typeInput );


    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', action , true);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/JSON");


request.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
      
      console.log(this.responseText);

      $ (function(){
        alert('Informations submitted');
    });
      
    }

 
};

request.send(data);







});
```

And the form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  method="POST" id="modifiyClientInformationsForm" action="/clients/client_numero/{{ $client ->id }}">
            @csrf

            
            
            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">
            
                <label for="name" class="InputLabel">Nom :</label>
                <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_name" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->name}}">
            
            </div>
            

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="prenom" class="InputLabel">Prénom(s) :</label>
            <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_prenom" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->prénom}}">

            </div>

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="contact" class="InputLabel">Contact :</label>
                <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_contact" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->contact}}">

            </div>

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="email" class="InputLabel">Email :</label>
            <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_email" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->email}}">

            </div>

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="ville" class="InputLabel">Ville :</label>
            <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_ville" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->ville}}">

            </div>

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="pays" class="InputLabel">Pays :</label>
            <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_pays" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->pays}}">

            </div>

            <div class="InputAndLabelDiv">

                <label for="type" class="InputLabel">Type du client :</label>
            <input id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_type" type="text" class="MyInput"  value="{{$client->type_du_client}}">

            </div>
           


        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button  class="btn btn-large  MonButon" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          <button type="submit"  id="modifiyClientInformationsForm_submitButton" class="btn btn-success btn-large Monbuton"  > <span class="icon-ok"></span> Enregistrer</button>

        </div>
        
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is 'findOrFail' and not 'findOrFails'. This is why you get 'call to undefined method'.

Comment: Pfff...what a mistake...Thanks...I haven't seen the 's'. The page is loading now with success.

Comment: But please why I steel not see the data apend in the formData object  ?

Comment: @DOUHADJI How do you try to get the formData in the controller?

Comment: Questions that are the result of a typo are off-topic and should not be answered. Leave a comment on the question and then flag for closure.

Comment: @miken32 ok yes you are right

Comment: @jon :I am using the debug mode of the browser

Comment: @miken32 Are you using chrome?